# Need to fix image scaling

Tags: java, android, image, zooming, scale

**Problem**: I have limited the maximum and minimum zoom, everything is OK, **but:**

- If I try to zoom less than the minimum, then to zoom+, it is necessary to do the same amount of motion in the opposite direction. The same is with zoom+. And on the technical side, it looks like this:

**values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]** changes, despite the fact that before this is:

```
m.reset();
m.setScale(sx1, sx1);
```

where **sx1** is a **FIXED** value. Here is my code:

```
       public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            try{

            saved_gest_scale = newScale;
            newScale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            scaleFactor = newScale / oldScale;

            target_img_width *= 1/scaleFactor;

            if (target_img_width > width)//limit max zoom
                {
                    //fit on screen:
                        m = new Matrix();
                        m.reset();
                        float w_coef = img_width / width;
                        float sx1 = 1/w_coef;
                        m.setScale(sx1, sx1);
                    ///========

                    //apply new size
                    float sx2 = target_img_width/width;
                    sx2 = 1/sx2;
                    m.setScale(sx2, sx2);

                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    m.getValues(values);

                    //center image:
                    float globalX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                    float globalY = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                    float wid = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]*img_width;
                    float heig = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]*img_height;
                    m.postTranslate(width/2 - wid/2, height/2-heig/2);

                    if (wid <= width)//limit min-zoom
                    {
                        newScale = sx1;
                        m = new Matrix();
                        m.reset();
                        m.setScale(sx1, sx1);
                        wid = sx1*img_width;
                        heig = sx1*img_height;
                        debug.setText(wid + "<width" + "mx=" + values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] );
                        m.postTranslate(width/2 - wid/2, height/2-heig/2);
                    }
                        iw.setImageMatrix(m);
                }

            oldScale = newScale;
            }catch (Exception xx)
            {
                debug.setText("detector "+ xx.toString());
            }
            return  true;
        }
```

Please help.

Comment: Very very unclear question. Please think about this carefully and come up with a concise and clear question

Comment: Please clarify your question or it will probably get down voted. Also consider breaking down your code to show relevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

Use one parameter `scale` wich is changed in the `onScale` method. Also use two constants `minScale` and `maxScale`. In the `onScale` method check if new scale fits in the acceptable interval, and if it does - redraw the image with new scale.

Right now your code is in mess. Somehow `limit min-zoom` check is located inside `limit max zoom`, but scaling methods are spread all around. Thus it's very unclean when a new scale becomes current and why it is working wrong.